# How to find out the actual rendered font in microsoft edge?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-edge, developer-tools, font-family

In chrome it is shown under computed style in dev tool, in firefox there is a 'font' tab when inspecting element.

How about in Microsoft Edge? How to find out which font is actually used from the font-family property?

Answer (score 2):

In the latest Insiders release of Windows 10 there is a new Fonts tab in F12 that will show you the rendered font information for a given element. For a local font it will look like:
[image: Local font inspection output: Arial (Local, System, 309 chars)]

For a font loaded over the network it will look like:
[image: Roboto used as Roboto script=all rev=1 (Network, WOFF2, 828 chars) @font-face { font-family: Roboto script=all rev=1; src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/N5Lbe1fy); font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; }]